# Error message when I try to run pdflatex with movie15 package

Tags: errors, movie15

I am trying to use package movie15 to include videos in my PDF produced by the command `pdflatex`, however all the time I use this command the followed part of massage rises:

```
(/usr/share/texmf-texlive/tex/latex/fancybox/fancybox.sty
Style option: `fancybox' v1.3 <2000/09/19> (tvz)
) (./movie15.sty (/usr/share/texmf-texlive/tex/latex/oberdiek/ifdraft.sty)
(/usr/share/texmf-texlive/tex/latex/ms/everyshi.sty)

! LaTeX Error: Command \hyperlinkmovie already defined.
               Or name \end... illegal, see p.192 of the manual.

See the LaTeX manual or LaTeX Companion for explanation.
Type  H <return>  for immediate help.
 ...                                              

l.4380 }
```

How should I proceed to avoid it?

Cheers!

PS: I have downloaded the file `movie15.sty` and place it in the same directory I run the command `pdflatex mylatexfile`

Comment: If you indent lines by 4 spaces, then they are marked as a code sample. You can also highlight the code and click the "code" button (with "101010" on it).

Comment: Could you please add a [minimal example](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-told-i-have-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that) that illustrates your problem (including the preamble).

Comment: Also (sorry for the triple post), usually you don't need to download packages—they should already be contained in your TeX distribution.

Comment: Apparently you are using two packages (or a class and a package) which both define the `\hyperlinkmovie`. As @Caramdir already states, we would need a full minimal example document to know which packages are used.

Comment: Just a wild guess: it seems that both the packages `multimedia` and `movie15` are being loaded; that will cause the error mentioned.

Comment: @Gonzalo: Please turn your comment into an answer.

Answer (score 6):

Without a MWE, I think the comment from Gonzalo Medina is the closest that can be got to an answer:

> Just a wild guess: it seems that both the packages `multimedia` and
>   `movie15` are being loaded; that will cause the error mentioned.

Comment: Hey I got the same problem, I had: \usepackage{multimedia} \usepackage{movie15} so I commented \usepackage{multimedia} a it worked for me. Thanks. %\usepackage{multimedia} \usepackage{movie15}

Comment: Yes. Both packages define the command `\hyperlinkmovie`.